# Correct way of passing this value while XHR post in Google Closure

Tags: javascript, this, google-closure-library

so I have a client side error logging module in google closure which keep track of all client error. These errors are stored in a queue. The idea is a new error pops up gets stored in the queue and after a certain time it is sent to the server and the queue is emptied. But in my code the callback function does not represent the correct instance of the model.

```
goog.provide('model.ErrorLogger');

/**
 * @constructor
 */
model.ErrorLogger = function() {
    window.onerror = goog.bind(this.somefucntion() this);
};
goog.addSingletonGetter(model.ErrorLogger);
model.ErrorLogger.prototype.errors = [];
```

There is a method which is responsible for storing the errors

```
model.ErrorLogger.prototype.notify = function(err){
    this.errors.push(err);
    this.sendReport();
}
```

This method sends the errors in the queue to the server

```
model.ErrorLogger.prototype.sendReport = function(){
    dataModel.xhrPost(rid,url,JSON.stringify(this.errors),function(responseData){
             this.errors = []; //This error queue should have contents but is showing undefined
    });
}
```

So when the response comes back to the callback function the errors queue shows undefined while debugging instead of showing the contents.  So basically the value of this should is not being correctly stored/passed. Basically I am not able to empty the error queue after it sends the errors to the server. Next time when new error pops up the old errors still present in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, since the "this" you are using in the callback function **doesn't point to your main object but to your callback function** 
you must either bind your callback function like this

```
model.ErrorLogger.prototype.sendReport = function(){
    dataModel.xhrPost(rid,url,JSON.stringify(this.errors),(function(responseData){
             this.errors = []; //This error queue should have contents but is showing undefined
    }).bind(this));
}
```

or subscribe to complete event fired by xhr object and use this approach (which is more clean)

```
goog.require('goog.net.XhrIo');

  var xhr = new goog.net.XhrIo();

  goog.events.listen(xhr, goog.net.EventType.COMPLETE, function(e) {
    obj = this.getResponseJson();
    // get your response here
  }, **false, this**);

  xhr.send(url);
```

more information available here https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/xhrio

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem

```
model.ErrorLogger.prototype.sendReport = function(){
    dataModel.xhrPost(rid,url,JSON.stringify(this.errors),goog.bind(function(responseData){
             this.errors = []; //This error queue should have contents but is showing undefined
    },this));
}
```

Explained: goog.bind is equivalent to function.prototype.bind, but that the first parameter is the function to be bound to, the second the "this" value that should be bound and any remaining parameters are bound to the functions formal parameters.

JavaScript has first class functions, but they aren't inheritly bound with a "this" value, so unless you bind it, the value depends on how it is called:

```
var x = { f : handler };
x.f(); // handler is called with "x" as the this value.
handler(); // unspecified this
```

Traditionally, if "this" value is unspecified, undefined, or null then it is coerced into the global this, "window" usually. However, if you are running in EcmaScript 5 strict mode, the value remains unchanged (unspecified is "undefined").